# Endless IAP loop

Tags: in-app-purchase, infinite-loop, sandbox, in-app-billing, in-app

I have deleted my sandbox user from my iTunes account and got stuck in an endless loop IAP transaction. I cant finish my previous transaction now. My question is that ,

1. How to clear the SKPaymentQueue?
2. How to break that endless loop?

I cant create that same sandbox user again as iTunes account prompts me that the userid has already been taken.

P.S I have placed [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction] in SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed and SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored but no luck :(

Kindly help, What should i do now?